# rails nested object form and namespaced controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, nested-forms

i have a nested object like this:

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :pages, :class_name => 'Work'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pages, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :work
end
```

and i have a form to create/edit a work, with fields for the nested page object. i followed [this post](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) for setting things up, so i'm using a helper so that my form creates a new page when you start out.

```
module AdminHelper

  def make_work(work)
    returning(work) do |w|
      w.pages.build if w.pages.empty?
    end
  end

end
```

then, in my form partial i have:

```
- form_for make_work(@work) do |f|
  ...
  - f.fields_for :page do |page_f|
    = page_f.label :text
    %br
    = page_f.text_area :text

  %p
    = f.submit "Submit"
```

that displays the fields for the page, but when it's submitted it looks for the create action in the works controller. the create action is in the admin works controller (namespaced), so that breaks.

i try it with the namespaced object, but if i do it this way it doesn't know about pages:

```
- form_for make_work([:admin, @work]) do |f|
  ...
```

how do i use the namespace with the nested object form so that it has the pages method, but posts to the namespaced admin/works controller?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have:

```
fields_for :pages do |page_f|
                ^
```

Also check in generated html if submit path for form is correct. In your case it should be something like:

```
/admin/works/3
```

EDIT:

Example for `fields_for`:

```
<% form_for @person do |person_f| %>
  <% person_f.fields_for :emails do |email_f| %>
     <%= email_f.text_field :address %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and it is for relationship like:

```
class Person
  has_many :emails
end
```

Make sure you didn't iterate over pages like this:

```
<% @work.pages.each do |page| %>
...
  <% fields_for :page do |p| %>
...
```

Comment: yeah, i had :pages, but it wouldn't render the nested form at all like that. when i use the plural i get and undefined method error for my 'text' object. it doesn't seem to get the relationship unless i use the singular?

Comment: I use similar relationships and I always use plural version. I added example from my code.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution, but you could just drop your `make_work` helper, target the form with `[:admin, @work]` (I can never remember that syntax) and just do the `w.pages.build` call in your controller, e.g.:

controller:

```
@work = Work.new
@page = @work.pages.build
```

view:

```
-form_for [:admin, @work] ...
  -f.fields_for @page ...
```

Comment: i'm trying the @work.pages.build in my controller now, and leaving out the helper. i get an unknown attribute error in admin/works_controller#create. i'm pretty stumped.

Comment: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in Admin/worksController#create

unknown attribute: page

Answer (score 0):

turns out i had something wrong in my work model. i had:

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :pages, :class_name => 'Work'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pages, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

the 'class_name => 'Work'' was causing it to look for the 'text' object on the Work class, rather than the Page class. now it works!